# Dependencies specified in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

Let's say I have a client-side app (say an Ember application)

I define my application's package.json with the various dependencies.

```
    {
    name: "my-app",
    dependencies: {
       "dep1" : "1.0.0"
    },
    devDependencies: {
       "devDep1" : "1.0.0"
    }
    }
```

My question is

1. Do I not have to worry about the dependencies which "dep1" itself would have? Meaning not define those sub-dependencies in my
   package.json, coz they'll be taken care of in the package.json which
   "dep1" itself would define?
2. Any situations where we would define the dependencies in our own app..e.g. say our app uses "jquery" while even dep1 requires "jquery"
   ...Ideally, we would not define "jquery" in our own package.json in this case...But any use case where we might have to like different version required by our app...in this case, how would the overriding behavior work meaning what version gets considered?
3. Is this handled similarly across all package managers like npm, bower?

P.S: Any additional info in an Ember engine environment would be useful as well (meaning when using a Parent app with child addon, etc.)

Comment: 1 : Node modules automatically has sub dependencies. You don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

- You don't have to worry about any dependent packages. They are read from the package's package.json that you have required and installed.
- This is consistent across all package managers.

--- UPDATE ---

npm dependencies are nested. This means that each package can have a separate version of the same package as a dependency. In your case, if a package requires "jquery" and you want to use a different version of "jquery", you can install any version as per your need and that will be the only version available to you and not any other version required by any dependency of your package.

Comment: Thanks...Just updated my question...Could you provide an input on bullet point 2 (version)

Comment: So npm would resolve it...But does bower also use nested-dependencies ? My guess is it has a flat dependency structure unlike npm ? Is that true ?

Comment: Bower is created solely for the front-end development and is optimised with that in mind. It uses flat dependency tree, requiring only one version for each package, reducing the page load. It mainly aims for minimal resource load.

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` or `npm` uses [**nested-dependencies**](https://maxogden.com/nested-dependencies.html) which mean a dependency can have a own dependency on sub-dependency and so on. `npm` will resolve those dependency by itself.
This allows different modules to have different version of same dependency.

Comment: So npm would resolve it...But does bower also use nested-dependencies ? My guess is it has a flat dependency structure unlike npm ? Is that true ?

Comment: bower uses flat dependency